# Show that any degree $k$ polynomial divides $e_q=x^q-x$ with $q=p^{km}$ in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Let $p$ be a prime and $P(x)\in\mathbb Z_p[x]$ a monic irreducible polynomial with $\deg{P}=k$.  Let $q=p^{mk}$ for any positive integer $m$ and define $e_q(x) = x^q-x$.  I want to prove that $P$ divides $e_q$.

I know that the field $\mathbb Z_p$ is a subfield of $\mathbb Z_q$.  Moreover, in $\mathbb Z_{q}[x]$ the polynomial $e_q$ splits completely because every element is a root.  I have been trying to show that $P$ divides $e_q$ in $\mathbb Z_q$, and I've been thinking that there might be some reason why $P$ must also split completely over $\mathbb Z_q$.  However, I can't see why $P$ would need to have any particular factorization, or equivalently, why it should have any particular roots in $\mathbb Z_q$.

Perhaps $\mathbb Z_q$ is the splitting field of $P$?  What do I know about the splitting field?  It's $\mathbb Z_{p}[x]/(P)$ which is a $\mathbb Z_p$ vector space and the dimension of this vector space is the degree of $P$, which is $k$.  So the number of elements in this vector space is $p^k$.  So the splitting field of $P$ is $\mathbb Z_{p^k}$ if I have all that right, and so this looks like a dead-end.  Or at least I don't see how to carry this line of thought further.

I think this question is asking the same thing as mine: [Irreducible polynomial f in polynomial ring of finite field order n divides a particular polynomial if and only if degree of f divides n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590291/irreducible-polynomial-f-in-polynomial-ring-of-finite-field-order-n-divides-a-pa)

But I don't understand the algebraic closure well enough to know how to use the hints.

Comment: Mentioning $\Bbb{Z}_q$ here is somewhere between wrong and misleading. The field of $q$ elements is denoted $\Bbb{F}_q$ or $GF(q)$. It has nothing to do with the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ simply because the latter is not a field unless $q$ is a prime. You do seem to know that $\Bbb{F}_q=\Bbb{Z}_p[x]/(P)$ etc. I just needed to get that off my chest.

Comment: What you need to observe here is that any zero of $P$ belongs to a $k$-dimensional field, call it $K$, that has $p^k$ elements. By Lagrange $\alpha^{p^k-1}=1$. But $p^k-1\mid p^{mk}-1$, so we also have $\alpha^{p^{mk}-1}=1$. Consequently, every zero of $P$ is also a zero of $x^{p^{mk}}-x=e_q(x)$. This implies that $P\mid e_q(x)$ You do need that the zeros of $P$ are simple to conclude, but that may have been explained earlier. All depending how the presentation of this material was organized.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The boundary between what I know and what I don't know is probably not a clear line. :)  I probably half-understand these ideas.  Sorry for the wrong notation.